# ssh root@$host.list < ./remotescript.sh

Tags: shell-script, ssh, remote

I'm using this command a lot to run a script on remote servers:

```
ssh root@servername.eu < ./remotescript.sh
```

It works quite well.
Now that there are more servers I'm wondering how I could use a list of these servers with that command... like this for example:

```
ssh root@$server.list < ./remotescript.sh
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

-Sam

Comment: You may want to look into Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your file with hosts is something like:

```
server1
server2
server3
```

you can use code like:

```
while read host
do
ssh root@$host < ./remotescript.sh
done <server.list
```